# How to copy newest file and related files with extensions into another directory from the command line

Tags: linux, command-line

Let's say I have a directory that has the following files:

one.txt,
one.txt.tmp1,
one.txt.tmp2,
two.txt,
two.txt.tmp1,
two.txt.tmp2,
... and others that look like this

I want to find the newest (by time stamp) file, let's say it's two.txt, and all of it's tmp files (two.tmp1 and two.tmp2) and copy them over to a knew directory. I know how to copy the newest file:

cp -p "`ls -dtr1 "$SRC_DIR"/* | tail -1`" "$DEST_DIR"

But I need all of the related files. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: can you provide an update whether it worked or not?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, the goal is clear. I hacked something really quick in bash that uses bash syntax only

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

latest_file () 
{ 
    local file latest 
    local src="$1"
    local dst="$2"
    for file in "${src:-.}"/*;
    do
        [[ $file -nt $latest ]] && latest="$file";
    done;
    cp -v "${latest%.*}"* "$dst"
}

main() {
  if (($# < 2)); then
    printf '%s\n' "Usage: ${0##*/} [src] [dst]"
    exit 1
  else
    latest_file "$@"
  fi
}
main "$@"
```

1. Put this content in a script called  `latest` no extension needed
2. Make it executable
   `chmod u+x latest`
3. Run `./latest source destination`  # source is your source directory and destination is the destination directory to copy files to
4. If you run it without arguments as `./latest` it will show you what to do